# Docker: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache'

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm

I encountered a permission error while trying to build a docker container in a React app. 
I tried to make use of the community answers, but didn't help. 
Following related [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules?page=1&tab=oldest#tab-top) I tried:

- I get the current user: `id -un`
- tried this: `sudo chown -R myUser:myUser /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
- this also threw the same error: `sudo chown -R ownerName: /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
- same with this: `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
- adding a user didn't help: `sudo chown -R $USER /app/node_modules`
- tried to give permission installing this: `sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`
- another try was to remove **node_modules** and install specifying `sudo`: `sudo npm install`

Adding this to `docker-compose` file, didn't help either:

```
environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

I am trying to build with this command: `docker-compose up --build`

Dockerfile.dev file

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
```

error

```
Building web
Step 1/6 : FROM node:alpine
 ---> 50389f7769d0
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR '/app'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bb4d4ffdeb02
Step 3/6 : COPY package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c4e5fce6b1e0
Step 4/6 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9383aea4aba6
Step 5/6 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 98ea3037694f
Step 6/6 : CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6edf3365a6db
Successfully built 6edf3365a6db
Successfully tagged app_web:latest
Starting app_web_1 ... 
Starting app_web_1 ... done
Attaching to app_web_1
web_1  | 
web_1  | > app@0.1.0 start
web_1  | > react-scripts start
web_1  | 
web_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.20.0.2/
web_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
web_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
web_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
web_1  | Starting the development server...
web_1  | 
web_1  | Failed to compile.
web_1  | 
web_1  | EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache'
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you try `chmod 777 -R` in the Dockerfile? just to make sure what the problem is..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this
[Docker - EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67187750/docker-eacces-permission-denied-mkdir-app-node-modules-cache)

this worked for me

```
RUN chown -R node:node /app/node_modules
```

or sh into docker container and run

```
chown -R node:node /app/node_modules
```

Comment: I realized this affected ubuntu users who had not set up non-sudo docker. If I `RUN mkdir -p /app/node_modules` and then `RUN chown node:node /app/node_modules` before `npm install` then it worked equally well but much faster.

Comment: the RUN step worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this to you Dockerfile

```
RUN chown -R node:node /app/node_modules

USER node
```

Between `COPY . .`  and `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"`]